Передача изображения в Alertmanager для пересылки в Telegram
Есть ли возможность передать изображение через Alertmanager в Telegram?
К примеру:
groups:
- name: example
  rules:
  - alert: HighErrorRate
    expr: job:request_error_rate{job="myjob"} > 0.5
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: "High error rate detected"
      description: "Error rate is {{ $value }}"
      image_path: "http://path.to/image.jpg"
    receivers:
      - telegram-notifications

